# Proving the inequality $3+8\sum\limits_{cyc} {\frac{b^2c^2(3b^2+3c^2+7a^2)}{7a^2+6bc}}\ge 9(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Tags: inequality

Prove the following inequality:

> $$3+8\sum_{cyc} {\frac{b^2c^2(3b^2+3c^2+7a^2)}{7a^2+6bc}}\ge 9(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

$ ab+bc+ca=3$ and $a,b,c\ge0$

The inequality is really hard so I have not even a clue how to start ...
The only thing that I came up is that $3$ must be transformed to something with a degree of $2$.

Comment: This is not a particularly elegant expression. Where did it comes from?

Comment: Found it on aops.

Comment: What's aops? ...

Comment: Art Of Problem Solving
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=613250

Comment: Your question differs from the AOPS one - maybe you missed the $3c^2$ and wrote $3^2$ instead here?

Comment: @Macavity thank you, that was my mistake.